# Template with STL algorithms slows down function a lot

Tags: c++, templates, stl

because pre-computing some keys into a `std::vector` saved me some time on the followed `std::sort`(before that the keys were recomputed every time) and I wanted to reuse it on different places, I tried to template this code:

```cpp
void myFunction() {
    QList<const Object*> objects = getObjectsList();
    const SomeCapturedType* someCapturedType = getCapturedType();

    typedef std::pair<double, const Object*> Pair;
    typedef std::vector<Pair> Transformed;
    Transformed transformed = Transformed(objects.length());

    std::transform(objects.begin(), objects.end(), transformed.begin(), [someCapturedType ](const Object* obj) {
        return std::make_pair(someCapturedType->lenghtyComputation(obj), obj);
    });

    std::sort(transformed.begin(), transformed.end());
    std::transform(transformed.begin(), transformed.end(), objects.begin(), [](Pair pair) { return pair.second; });
}
```

into this code:

```cpp
template <class T1, class T2, class Lambda>
void transformThenSortList(QList<T1>& objects, Lambda&& callback) {
    typedef std::pair<T2, T1> Pair;
    typedef std::vector<Pair> Transformed;
    Transformed transformed = Transformed(objects.length());
    std::transform(objects.begin(), objects.end(), transformed.begin(), [callback](T1 obj) { return std::make_pair(callback(obj), obj); });
    std::sort(transformed.begin(), transformed.end());
    std::transform(transformed.begin(), transformed.end(), objects.begin(), [](Pair pair) { return pair.second; });
}

void myFunction() {
    QList<const Object*> objects = getObjectsList();
    const SomeCapturedType* someCapturedType = getCapturedType();

    transformThenSortList<const Object*, double>(objects, [someCapturedType](const Object* obj) { return someCapturedType->lenghtyComputation(obj); });
}
```

but the time taken by my function just exploded, do you have any reasons why ?

Comment: Do you have a profiler? Measure where the time sink is.

Comment: What's your benchmark? Also, are optimizations enabled?

Comment: You're passing a lot of stuff by value. Probably not an issue (your lambda has very little state and your actual types are pointers, not values, so copy is cheap), but for other use cases you'd be wasting work on the copies. Presumably there's no need to capture by value, so `[callback](T1 obj) { return std::make_pair(callback(obj), obj); }` could be `[&callback](T1& obj) { return std::make_pair(callback(obj), obj); }` (possibly `const T1& obj` since you shouldn't need to mutate it in a key computation function) to capture by reference.

Comment: Similarly, when undecorating, you receive the `Pair` by value and return the second element by copy, when the input is expiring anyway, so you probably want: `std::transform(transformed.begin(), transformed.end(), objects.begin(), [](Pair& pair) { return std::move(pair.second); });` to avoid the copy of the `Pair` and replace copy construction of the return value with move construction. Probably made a mistake or two in there, and like I said, when `T1` is a pointer and `T2` is a `double` it gains nothing, but if you want this to be useful for other types, avoiding copies is a good idea.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: When `callback` is a lambda wrapping `someCapturedType->lenghtyComputation` it should be functionally equivalent, right? With optimizations on the compiler should undo all the wrapping anyway.

Comment: Probably a good idea to make the initial `transform` call use `std::make_move_iterator` on the input iterators for the same reasons (move out all the values to put in the decorated `vector<Pair>`, sort them, move back all the values after, no copy construction at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I changed my template to this for more generalization:

```cpp
template <class T1, class T2, class Lambda> void transformThenSortList(QList<T1>& objects, Lambda&& transformLambda) {
    typedef std::pair<T2, T1> Pair;
    typedef std::vector<Pair> Transformed;
    Transformed transformed = Transformed(objects.length());

    std::transform(
        objects.begin(), objects.end(), std::make_move_iterator(transformed.begin()), [&transformLambda](const T1& obj) { return std::make_pair(transformLambda(obj), obj); });
    std::sort(transformed.begin(), transformed.end());
    std::transform(transformed.begin(), transformed.end(), objects.begin(), [](Pair& pair) { return std::move(pair.second); });
}
```

Although, I tried switching back to the original code and had the expected time measurements. So I have no idea why at the time of posting I measured more than 1 minute for this code supposed to run in about 12 seconds. I immediately posted because I assumed there were issues with my template, but as pointed out here there are none since I'm using pointers.

Thanks for your comments which made me improve my code.